# Can't call stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm a beginner at C#. I can't call a stored procedure.

My stored procedure is this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE USP_login
    @us VARCHAR(20),
    @pwd VARCHAR(20)
AS
BEGIN TRAN
    BEGIN TRY
        SELECT * 
        FROM dbo.KhachHang 
        WHERE tenDangNhap = @us AND matKhau = @pwd
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRAN
        RETURN 0
    END CATCH

    COMMIT TRAN
    RETURN 1
GO
```

In my C# code, I use this function to call the `USP_login` stored procedure but it doesn't work:

```
public bool loginStored(string us, string pwd)
{
    object[] sqlParams =
    {
         new SqlParameter  ("@userName", us),
         new SqlParameter  ("@passWord", pwd),
    };

    var rs = db.Database.SqlQuery<bool>("USP_login @userName, @passWord", sqlParams).SingleOrDefault();
    return rs;
}
```

Error message in screenshot:

[image: Error Message]

Comment: the error is telling you what's wrong.. are you sure that the connection string in the .Config file is configured properly..? also you don't need a transaction or rollback for a simple Select query as you have here `SELECT * FROM dbo.KhachHang WHERE tenDangNhap=@us AND matKhau=@pwd` read up on how to do some basic Sql query's and what `Select *` means in regards to performance if you are only looking for 1 condition or checking 1 column

Comment: Don't use 'var' unless you have to like with a complex linq.  There is no reason you need to use var in this case.  If you defined the variables properly you would get a compiler error which is easier to fix than a runtime error.  Pressing the 'Copy exception detail to the clipbaord' and then pasting into notepad will give a the full stacktrace error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like `SELECT * ...` is returning more than just a single `bool`.  (Based on the query, clearly the table has *at least* two fields, `tenDangNhap` and `matKhau`.)  But that's what you told the code to expect:

```
db.Database.SqlQuery<bool>(/.../)
```

Either select only the column you want:

```
SELECT SomeBooleanValue FROM dbo.KhachHang WHERE tenDangNhap=@us AND matKhau=@pwd
```

**Or** specify the correct type that can be expected for each record (which may be a custom class that you need to define):

```
db.Database.SqlQuery<SomeObjectType>(/.../)
```